# Can I get an Italian student visa with a criminal record in Germany?

Tags: schengen, germany, schengen-visas, criminal-records

I'm from the Middle East. In 2015, I traveled to Germany and some other European countries for a month. In the last days in Berlin, my friend and I did something stupid and stole something small, just to find out whether we would be caught; we were drunk. We were, and the police recorded the offence but, because it was our first offence, we were free to go, but we had to sign a police document.

I have been accepted at universities in Italy for my Master's, but I am afraid to apply for a visa at the Embassy. Is a person's history shared between Schengen countries? Will Italy give me student visa or would I be refused because of the German police record?

Comment: What was the exact nature and content of the 'police document' you signed?

Comment: I steal a glove from store, they just saw my passport and i signed a paper that wrote i know that i steal something and i dont do it again. In getting out of Germany there was no problem at all.

Comment: Was the police document signed on the same day or later? Does the word "Einstellung" appear anywhere?

Comment: Since you seem to have a strong interest in visiting Italy, I think the most straightforward action would be go to the Italian ambassy and ask the visa. The worst that can happen is that you lose some time and money and get the visa denied. And I sincerely doubt that the episode that you describe will be enough to cause a denial (there could be other reasons, though).

Comment: Put another way: If the answer were "there is 90% chance of denial and 10% chance of approval"... would you just drop the issue or would you try just to see if the 10% possibility happens? Seems that you have invested enough time and money to just drop the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Edited after the comments.

---

**Does a criminal record in a different Schengen country affect visa applications?**

Criminal data *may* be entered into the Schengen Information System ([SIS II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Information_System)). As Tor-Einar pointed out, there is no complete and automatic information-sharing between the police and judiciary in the Schengen area.

**Do you have a criminal record?**

Germany has the Bundeszentralregister for criminal convictions or related data. You do not have one of those, or you would have noticed. Should an official form ask if you have been *convicted of a crime,* the answer is no with regard to this incident.

Germany has the Zentrales Staatsanwaltschaftliches Verfahrensregister for open or finished criminal investigations. You might have an entry in there. Should a form ask if you have been *charged with a crime,* the answer might be yes, depending on how far this went before it was dismissed.

I'm a bit puzzled regarding the lack of paperwork. Even if the case had been closed, you should have been informed officially. Did you give a correct and current address?

Comment: That was the exact day and hour at the mall, they came saw my passport i signed the document and they leave, i didnt go to any police office. The student visa is schengen. What do you think ? is it going to be a problem?

Comment: I didnt get any mail at all.

Comment: Do you have the document? What is the headline? And it may or may not be a problem, you should apply and tell the truth if it comes up.

Comment: No they dont give me anything, thanks for your help. So you dont know the schengen countries share their police informations or not?

Comment: This answer is purely speculative and does not really add anything of interest or relevance. The OP already knows that he has to apply for an Italian visa. German and Italian authorities do not regularly share information from penal registers, but German authorities are notified about all Italian visa applications and may object if they have grounds for that in a national register.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, the OP probably isn't in the *penal* register. Yes, that is speculative, but that is all that is left without paperwork.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, edited. Do you like this better?

Comment: @o.m. I'm not sure. Due to lack of details from the OP about what actually happened, I don't think the question can be answered with anything but speculations, which do not answer the question. In any case, the question is off-topic, since it is about obtaining a long-term visa.